# blk_update_request: I/0 error when installing Kubuntu

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

my computer stopped at the following error message when restarting it at the end of Kubuntu installing process. I am a total newbie to Linux and I have no idea what went wrong and if it's fixable.

Edit: after 30 minutes of waiting it suddenly restarted and Kubuntu seems to work fine now. If anyone knows why this error happened and if it will cause me problems later, I'd like to know and also learn more about computers. :)

[Picture of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpQfF.jpg)

Comment: You haven't provided any release details; but you have a device error on sda.  If that device proves to be your hdd, you have an hardware issue on your drive you should check (ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) however if sda is the installation media; you didn't perform ISO validation prior to write to media; or your write of ISO to media was faulty (did you verify it as per your *unstated* release)

Comment: It looks like the media you installed from had a problem.